# How to utilize Oracle query hint on QSqlQuery?

Tags: oracle

There is a ascending default index on column “wimindex”.
 I want to retrieve just recent one using oracle hint like below.
 But it seems that Oracle query hint doesn’t work.
 Of course this query is working well on Oracle sql/plus.
 Just QT QSqlQuery doesn’t work.
 Would you help me ? or any hint?

Below is my code.
thanks…

```
QString lastWimIdxQuery = “SELECT **/*+ index_rs_desc(VIOLATE, VIOLATE) */**  WIMINDEX FROMVIOLATE WHERE wimindex > 0 and rownum =1”;
query.exec(lastWimIdxQuery); 
int fieldNo = query.record().indexOf(“WIMINDEX”); 
if(query.next()) { 
this->m_lastWimIdx = query.value(fieldNo).toInt();
 qDebug()<<this->m_thread_name << “ : “ << this->m_lastWimIdx; 
}else { return; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that QT is perhaps eating the comment/hint and not passing it to the database? Create a view in the database using your query and select from that to confirm this hypothesis:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW LastWMIdxView as 
SELECT **/*+ index_rs_desc(VIOLATE, VIOLATE) */**  WIMINDEX 
  FROM VIOLATE 
 WHERE wimindex > 0 and rownum =1;
```

Then use that view in your code:

```
QString lastWimIdxQuery = "SELECT wmindex FROM LastWMIdxView";
```

Alternatively, you could run your query as is and check the v$sql view to see what was parsed:

```
SELECT sql_text
  FROm v$sql
 WHERE UPPER(sql_text) LIKE '%VIOLATE%';
```

If it turns out that the comments are being eaten, unless there's a way to control that in QT I think you'll probably have to use the view as outlined above.